# Extract RGBA from Matplotlib maps

Tags: python, opencv, rgba

I'm trying to convert a figure created with Matplotlib imshow into RGBA values but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
```

This is my code:

```
speed0 = speed[0, :, :].values   

figsize = (7, 7)
cbarkw = dict(shrink=0.6, extend='both')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
i = plt.imshow(speed0, origin='lower')
cbar = plt.colorbar(i, **cbarkw)
plt.axis('off')

def matplotlib_to_opencv(i):
    image = i._rgbacache
    r, g, b, a = cv2.split(image)
    return np.flipud(cv2.merge([b, g, r, a]))

image = matplotlib_to_opencv(i)
```

Where speed0 is a wind dataset of (192x111). I think 'image' is a null cache and hence cv2.split can't read it but I don't know how to make it work properly. Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure _rgbacache is a thing? it seems that it returns None

Comment: I was expecting to get an error in case of it doesn't exist. It has other function, i.to_rgba, but the following error pops up: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you should do to get what you want is change the call to make_image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

speed = np.random.random((4, 192, 111))

speed0 = speed[0, :, :]

figsize = (7, 7)
cbarkw = dict(shrink=0.6, extend='both')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
im = plt.imshow(speed0, origin='lower')

cbar = plt.colorbar(im, **cbarkw)
plt.axis('off')


def matplotlib_to_opencv(im):
    image = im.make_image('TkAgg')
    # this returns
    #         -------
    #         image : (M, N, 4) uint8 array
    #             The RGBA image, resampled unless *unsampled* is True.
    #         x, y : float
    #             The upper left corner where the image should be drawn, in pixel
    #             space.
    #         trans : Affine2D
    #             The affine transformation from image to pixel space.
    #         """
    # So you just want the first 
    r, g, b, a = cv2.split(image[0])
    return np.flipud(cv2.merge([b, g, r, a]))

image = matplotlib_to_opencv(im)


plt.show()
```

Since I did not have your dataset I'm not 100% sure this is what you wanted. But I believe it should work.